# How to extract pure string from a constant string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I print the value of a CFString constant e.g. an AddressBook label in the console, the output value is `_$!<home>!$_`. How do I extract only the pure value, e.g home? ANy help would be greatly appreciated please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all string constants have all that gubbins around them - it just happens that someone decided that the address book ones do. Therefore, I don't think there's any built-in function to remove them.

That makes this problem a simple "How do I remove characters?" question. There are many solutions to this, but a simple one is:

```
NSString *label = @"_$!<home>!$_";

NSString *rawLabel = [[label stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_$!<" withString:@""] 
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">!$_" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Thank you. I just assumed it would be a feature of all constants rather than an AB quirk.

Answer (score 7):

If you're displaying the name of the property in your interface, use [the `ABCopyLocalizedPropertyOrLabel` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABUtilitiesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABCopyLocalizedPropertyOrLabel) or [the `ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName` function](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName) instead of attempting to extract a name from the private implementation-detail value of the constant.

If you're doing something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@: %@", kABURLsProperty, URLsValue);
```

Try this instead:

```
//In a header
#define STRING_FROM_NAME(name) @#name

//In the implementation
NSLog(@"%@: %@", STRING_FROM_NAME(kABURLsProperty), URLsValue);
```

This will print the name of the constant, which is much more recognizable, instead of the private implementation-detail value of the constant.

(Note that, since this is a *preprocessor* macro, it doesn't follow variables. It just creates a string from whatever text you pass as the first argument; it does not attempt to reverse-lookup a string. So, if you pass a variable name, you will get the name of your variable in the output.)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
NSString *label = (NSString*)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(contact, index));
```

Answer (score -2):

Here the code snipped I use because `ABCopyLocalizedPropertyOrLabel` is Mac OS X only at the moment:

```
NSString *labelTranslation = @"";
if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Home>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Home";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Mobile>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Mobile";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Work>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Work";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<WorkFAX>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Work (Fax)";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Main>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Main";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<HomeFAX>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Home (Fax)";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Pager>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Pager";
else if ([label isEqualToString:@"_$!<Other>!$_"])
    labelTranslation = @"Other";
```

Comment: On the iPhone, try ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName instead.